# Html Encode in ASP.NET Web Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, html-encode

I have a file called TopicTree.ascx.cs which I am trying to output encoded strings like so:

```
            string subject = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(0);
            string topic = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(1);

            subject = subject.Trim();
            topic = topic.Trim();

            string en_subject = Server.HtmlEncode(subject);
            string en_topic = Server.HtmlEncode(topic);

            string output = string.Format("<li><a href=\"searchresults.aspx?type=topics&subject={1}&topic={2}\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">{0}</a></li>", topic, en_subject, en_topic);
```

But when I actually see the output on the screen, it isn't encoded. What's wrong?

Comment: If "output" is supposed to be rendered as HTML, what you are looking for is URLEncode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the link URL, you want `Server.UrlEncode()` instead of `Server.HtmlEncode()`.

But for the link display, you want `Server.HtmlEncode(topic)` on the topic as well.